# Get name of surrounding class from within nested class

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a nested class within an outer class and from within the inner class I would like to get the name of the outer class via reflection at runtime.

```
public abstract class OuterClass // will be extended by children
{
    protected class InnerClass // will also be extended
    {
        public virtual void InnerMethod()
        {
            string nameOfOuterClassChildType = ?;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible in c#?

Edit: I should add, that I want to use reflection and get the name from a child class which extens from OuterClass, which is the reason, I don't know the concrete type at compile time.

Comment: How about just `= nameof(OuterClass);` ?

Comment: I've added some more information to my post. In my specific case I don't know the concrete type of OuterClass, and child classes will call base.InnerMethod() to get some basic data back. It would be convenient to use reflection instead of providing additional virtual methods to get to the name of encapsulating child class.

Comment: You have to be specific. Try this then: `GetType().DeclaringType.Name;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should parse out the name of the outer class:

```
public virtual void InnerMethod()
{
    Type type = this.GetType();

    // type.FullName = "YourNameSpace.OuterClass+InnerClass"

    string fullName = type.FullName;
    int dotPos = fullName.LastIndexOf('.');
    int plusPos = fullName.IndexOf('+', dotPos);
    string outerName = fullName.Substring(dotPos + 1, plusPos - dotPos - 1);

    // outerName == "OuterClass", which I think is what you want
}
```

Or, as @LasseVKarlsen proposed,

```
string outerName = GetType().DeclaringType.Name;
```

...which is actually a better answer.

Comment: I like Lasses answer the best. Works fine and is short. But parsing the assembly also seems to work. Mabye that can be a last resort for some special black magic circumstances. Thanks to you both!